# I have the following function which returns an array. I want to change its out put format

Tags: php, arrays

```
function Authorize(){


      if ($this->session->userdata('login_in') != 'TRUE') {
          redirect('Login', 'refresh');
      }

      $user_group_id = $this->session->userdata('user_group');

      if ($user_group_id != '') {
          $pre = $this->db->get_where('afro_user_group', array(
              'user_group_id' => $user_group_id
          ))->row();
          $this->Authorize = $pre;
          $array =  (array) $pre;
          $select = 'all';
          foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
              if ($value == 't'){
                  $select .= ',' ."'". $key."'";
              }
          }
            $array = (array) $select;
          $Authorized = array_map('strtoupper', $array);

        //die(print_r($Authorized));
         return $Authorized ;
      }
  }
}
```

dumping $Authorized gives the following result.

```
Array ( [0] => 'ALL','USER_GROUP_STATUS','USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_CREATE_DEPARTMENT' )
```

And I want to convert it like this... in order to use array_search, array filter functions.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ALL [1] => USER_GROUP_STATUS [2] => USER_GROUP_HAS_PERMISSION_CREATE_DEPARTMENT)
```

how can I do that.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
return $Authorized ;
```

to

```
$Authorized_new_format = explode(",", $Authorized[0]);
return [$Authorized_new_format];
```

This will break the explode the string and convert to multidimensional array;